# Call A Smart Contract Function With Another Deployed Smart Contract Address As "msg.sender " From Hardhat Test

Tags: solidity, hardhat, solidity-0.8.x, hardhat-deploy

I have The Following Function in my Smart Contract

```
 function functionName(uint256 param1, address param2)
        external
        override
    {
        require(msg.sender == marketContract, "only market contract");
```

The Market Contract Address is Set in the Constructor

```
 constructor(address marketContractAddr) 
        {
        marketContract = marketContractAddr;
        }
```

I Have Then Written The Following in my Test in Hardhat in the beforeEach I do the Following

```
    marketContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Market");
    market = await marketContract.deploy();
    await market.deployed();

    mediaContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Media");
    media = await mediaContract.deploy(market.address);
    await media.deployed();
```

and get my signers using the following

```
[owner,addr1,addr2] = await ethers.getSigners();
```

I Then Want to in my test make the following call

```
 const res = await media.functionName(1,addr2.address)
 await res.wait();
```

The Above is expected to revert due to the following require statement

```
 require(msg.sender == marketContract, "only market contract");
```

How Can One Call This Function With The Deployed Market Contract as the `msg.sender` ?

I Have Tried The Following

1. Tried Using connect when making the call from my test seen below

```
 const res = await media.connect(market).functionName(1,addr2.address)
```

which fails with the following

" Error: VoidSigner cannot sign transactions "

I Then Tried The Following which also fails

```
 const res = await media.functionName(1,addr2.address{
       from:market.address
     })
```

I Then Tried Running My Test After Deploying My Contracts to my Local  "npx hardhat node"

I Then Receive the following error

"Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"name":"ProviderError"

I Realized that when running

```
market = await marketContract.deploy();
```

A New Address Was Created For My Market Contract and it didn't match what I had already deployed to my local network

so I tried Recreating my Contracts within my test at the deployed local addresses

```
    const marketRes = await artifacts.readArtifact("Market");
    const marketResContract = new ethers.Contract("0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3", marketRes.abi, ethers.provider);
```

Still With no Success receiving the following errors depending on weather I use
`connect` or `from`

"invalid signer or provider" and "Contract with a Signer cannot override from"

It Seems Pretty Straight Forward but cannot seem to find success would really appreciate any guidance

Thank you Team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Team Have Finally Resolved It

One Has To First

```
    
  await hre.network.provider.request({
  method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
  params: [market.address],
});
```

Then Get The Signer Using the Following

```
 const signer = await ethers.getSigner(market.address);
```

One Can Then Use the Signer In The Connect Of The Contract Call From Within Your Hardhat Test

```
await media.connect(signer).functionName(1,addr2.address);
```

and end impersonating the contract using the following

```
  await hre.network.provider.request({
  method: "hardhat_stopImpersonatingAccount",
  params: [market.address],
});
```

I Hope This Can Help Anyone Else Facing this Issue

Thank You

Comment: It worked partially because now I have `InvalidInputError: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The max upfront cost is: 499021982986307664 and the sender's account only has: 0`

Comment: ok I solved this sending first some ETH to my contract with `signer.sendTransaction({to: MyContract.address, value: parseEther("1")})` for example

Answer (score 0):

You have to code the function call into the Market contract itself, then protect that function with whatever validation logic you need. Dummy implementation:

```
interface ICalledByMarket {
  function functionName(uint256 param1, address param2) external;
}

contract CalledByMarket is ICalledByMarket {
  function functionName(uint256 param1, address param2) {
    // do stuff
  }

  // rest of your code
}

contract Market {
  `onlyAuthorizedCaller` is a modifier with whatever protection logic you want
  function callOtherContract(uint256 param1, address param2) public is onlyAuthorizedCaller {
    ICalledByMarket(otherContractAddress).functionName(param1, param2);
  }

  // rest of your code
}
```

You can also use `.call` syntax as described [here](https://medium.com/@blockchain101/calling-the-function-of-another-contract-in-solidity-f9edfa921f4c) or any other number of resources to achieve the same effect

Comment: Hello Sir Thanks For The Response that is already my implementation the issue is not the solidity smart contract but when calling the functions from HardHat Tests hope this clarifies details of challenge I am facing