# How to override transactionObject `{from: xxx }` in hardhat?

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, hardhat

I'm trying to write a test to check if an approved address can transfer the owner's token. However, whenever I try to call `token.transferFrom()` with a transactionObject of `{from: approved.address}`, it errors out with:

```
Error: Contract with a Signer cannot override from 
(operation="overrides.from", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.6.0)
```

It seems the transferObject only accepts a `{from: owner.address}` because the owner is the one who received the minted token.
How can I properly override the transactionObject in order to test an approved address calling the method?

Relevant code is below...

```js
context("given approvals", function () {
  beforeEach(async function () {
    // The sender (owner) allows the approved address to mess with this one NFT
    await token.approve(approved.address, tokenId, {
      from: owner.address,
    });
  });

  // This works
  it("should allow the owner to transfer the token", async function () {
    await this.token.transferFrom(
      owner.address,
      anotherOwner.address,
      tokenId,
      {
        from: owner.address, // <- This works since it's from the owner
      }
    );
    expect(await this.token.ownerOf(tokenId)).to.be.equal(
      anotherOwner.address
    );
  });

  // This does not work
  // Error: Contract with a Signer cannot override from 
  it("should allow the approved address to transfer the token", async function () {
    await this.token.transferFrom(
      owner.address,
      anotherOwner.address,
      tokenId,
      {
        from: approved.address, // <- This doesn't work and errors
      }
    );
    expect(await this.token.ownerOf(tokenId)).to.be.equal(
      anotherOwner.address
    );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized how to do it from [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/122959/call-a-smart-contract-function-with-another-deployed-smart-contract-address-as?rq=1) and also the [official docs](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts.html#using-a-different-account)

Need to use the `connect()` method, keeping in mind you pass in the full `SignerWithAddress` object and NOT `SignerWithAddress.address`

```js
await this.token
  .connect(approved) // <- The solution
  .transferFrom(
    owner.address,
    anotherOwner.address,
    tokenId,
    {
      from: approved.address // <- Optional, to be more explicit
    }
);
```